# Saving output of t.test to dataframe when using mapply in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have two dataframes of the sort

```
a    b    c
1    2    3
2    3    3
1    2    3
```

with the same column names. I'm using

```
mapply(t.test, df1, df2)
```

to output the results of a t.text comparing the a,b, and c-type columns between the two dataframes. This yields (actual results):

```
        LHM                                      
statistic   -11.5671                                 
parameter   90.46322                                 
p.value     1.575918e-19                             
conf.int    Numeric,2                                
estimate    Numeric,2                                
null.value  0                                        
alternative "two.sided"                              
method      "Welch Two Sample t-test"                
data.name   "dots[[1L]][[23L]] and dots[[2L]][[23L]]"
        RaM                                      
statistic   -18.66368                                
parameter   172.2032                                 
p.value     3.200675e-43                             
conf.int    Numeric,2                                
estimate    Numeric,2                                
null.value  0                                        
alternative "two.sided"                              
method      "Welch Two Sample t-test"                
data.name   "dots[[1L]][[24L]] and dots[[2L]][[24L]]"
```

etc. etc. (I have ~180 columns of data in each dataframe). I need to store the names of the columns and their corresponding p-values in a matrix. It would also be helpful to store which dataframe contained the higher value in another column. Help?

Comment: the results of t.tests are actually stored in a list, so you can call out using the accessor `$p.value`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
mapply(function(x, y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, df1, df2)
# on my sample(/dummy) data.frames
#           a           b           c 
# 0.009963864 0.009963864 0.020204103
```

---

You can wrap it up with `stack` if you want a 2 column format `data.frame` like so:

```
stack(mapply(function(x, y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, df1, df2))
#        values ind
# 1 0.009963864   a
# 2 0.009963864   b
# 3 0.020204103   c
```

Comment: What if you wanted to also save the t-statistic in addition to the p-value?